# Github's CSS Styleguide

Tags: css, github

I was reading Github's styleguide(https://github.com/styleguide/css) when I saw this:

> - Use `//` for comment blocks (instead of `/* */`).

Every web-designer that I've read about says to NOT DO this, and use `/* */` instead. Why does Github recommends the other way?

Comment: GitHub seems to use SCSS, not purse CSS. SCSS supports `//`, CSS doesn't. As you can read at the *very top* of the page you linked to: *"Welcome to the GitHub CSS Styleguide. It's pretty rad. Before reading this, you should have a general understanding for specificity, the SCSS syntax, and KSS documentation."*

Comment: But I think that line refers to CSS not SCSS, because there's an specific section for SCSS.

Comment: True, but that might just be poorly organized. SCSS is a superset of CSS (I believe). Fact is that CSS does not recognize `//` as comment syntax.

Comment: @FelixKling is right, `//` in pure CSS is a syntax error.

Comment: I don't think they would make it poorly organized, but ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Felix Kling 1st comment on the question seems a perfect answer.

> GitHub seems to use SCSS, not pure CSS. SCSS supports //, CSS
>   doesn't. As you can read at the very top of the page you linked to:
>   "Welcome to the GitHub CSS Styleguide. It's pretty rad. Before reading
>   this, you should have a general understanding for specificity, the
>   SCSS syntax, and KSS documentation.